# how to build and "Vite" "lit-ts" project as a static website

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component, vite, lit-element

I created a project using Vite Lit Element Typescript. development server is working fine.
however when I run `npm run build` .It only out put complied js file to `/dist` folder No html and css files.

So how can I get the full static files. just like we get in ReactJs.

sample Vite project [link](https://vite.new/lit-ts)
vite [guide](https://vitejs.dev/guide/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `lit-ts` template for vite has a config that's building for [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode):

```js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/my-element.ts',
      formats: ['es'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: /^lit/,
    },
  },
})
```

You can remove that config and the build command will produce all the assets in `/dist` directory.

```js
export default {}
```